Nuxt Fetch always return 401 using cookies
I have a problem that makes me confused, I created a web that runs on http://localhost:3000 and a backend that runs on http://localhost:5050 with a fetch data with useFetch and $fetch in it, when I check after doing My authentication has got the cookies but when I access the page that requires authentication it returns 401, I also tried with Postman using same cookies everything went fine so I think the problem might not be from the backend side, I have also added the URL to ALLOWED_ORIGINS to the backend
here the codes
components/ListSN.vue
const { allSN: datasn } = await useSN()
console.log(datasn)

composable/serialnumber.ts
export const useSN = async () => {
  const { data, error } = await useFetch("/api/sn", {
    credentials: "include",
  });

  if (error.value) {
    throw createError({
      ...error.value,
      statusMessage: `Couldn't fetch data.` + error.value,
    });
  }

  const { allSN } = data.value;

  return { allSN };
};

server/api/sn/index.ts
import type { SerialNumbers } from "~/types/serialnumber";

export const allSN: SerialNumbers = [];

const apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:5050";

export default defineEventHandler(async () => {
  if (allSN.length) {
    return {
      allSN,
    };
  }

  const _allSN: [] = await $fetch(`${apiBaseUrl}/serialnumber`, {
    credentials: "include",
  });
  allSN.push(..._allSN);

  if (!allSN) {
    throw createError({
      statusCode: 404,
      message: "Data not fetched.",
    });
  }

  return {
    allSN,
  };
});


I really appreciate all the help provided

I missed header that must be use for send the cookies
this is updated code
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { req } = event;
  const cookies = req.headers.cookie;

  const _allSN: [] = await $fetch(`${apiBaseUrl}/serialnumber`, {
    credentials: "include",
    headers: cookies ? { cookie: cookies } : undefined,
  });

});



